# HTML Include file

Tags: html, server-side-includes

I am using an include file by doing:

```
<!--#include virtual="/includes/leftNav.shtml"-->
```

I changed the include file, and the changes are not picked up.
I'm guessing that they will be with a server restart; is it possible to have the changes picked up w/o a restart?

Comment: you don't need a server restart, its a client side include.

Comment: maybe this matters...i deploy the application in GlassFish with "/" as the context. I then change the context to "/foo" and deploy the EAR again, but with the name foo.ear. In effect, there are two applications running. The include change is not showing up in foo.ear whenn foo.ear is deployed

Comment: -1 What preprocessor are you using?  Are you using a content management system?  There's nowhere near enough information here to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There tends to be caching issues for any static content type extensions it really should work with just a ctrl+F5

Comment: any idea what the Mac equivalent is?

Comment: Hold down shift while clicking the refresh button. Or command+ctrl+r.

Answer (score 2):

The root level page is possibly cached, either by the server itself or the browser. Adding a query string to the request (i.e.: http://mysite.com/index.shtml?0827091630) might get you a new copy of your doc.

Answer (score 2):

[Server-side includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/ssi.html) don't need a server restart. They take immediate effect. If they don't work, it probably means that your Apache server is not configured to support server-side includes at all, or not for the type of file you are trying them on.